# Prevent cheating on savedata in iPhone

Tags: iphone

We can use sqlite, nsuserdefaults or ordinary file system for saving gamedata on iPhone. These data are usually stored in the Documents directory, but files under the Documents directory can be easily modified without JailBreak. (Actually some cheated scores were posted to the server before)

There are some ideas I considered to prevent cheating by modifying save data.

---

### Encrypt file

Simply encrypt data file and decrypt it on reading. It seems secure but the performance will be sacrified if the game need to update gamedata frequently.

### SQLite encryption

There are some encrypt extension libraries for sqlite. The problems are the cost and the licenses.

### Verifier / Checksum

Store the checksum of saved data and detect cheat by using it. It might cause FALSE POSITIVE result if the saving checksum failed by some reason.

### Keychain

Store data into keychain. But we can't use sqlite. And is it okay to store large data in keychain?

---

Each idea has a flaw. Can you give me any ideas?

Comment: Why would the checksum fail?   Btw, just posting a sign that says "Beware of Dog" keeps a lot of people out even if there is no dog.  A label that says "Cheaters will be excluded from the game" might help and would not cost anything.

Comment: I'd do a checksum of the database and store that value in the keychain, then validate that the keychain = db checksum on startup, return from background, etc.

Comment: Checksum will fail if we save data and checksum non-atomically. And we need transaction infrastructure to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One flaw in the design seems to be that you are trusting the local data. Instead I'd recommend that you treat the local data as unsafe user data.  That way, a user can manipulate it all they want, but you'll never send it to your server to be published.

When a user completes a game, have the game send the score to the server right away.  If you like, your server can send back a signed copy (hashed) that you can save wherever you want in whatever format you want. In your game, you could add a little "verified score" badge next to the scores that took place while they were online. If the verified score is manipulated, then the hash won't work, and (locally anyway) they'll loose their score.

If your user is offline, then their score cannot be verified.  You can still save it locally with all the signed scores, but don't have to worry about syncing up bad data at all.  Simply never send data to your server that was read from the local filesystem.

From a user experience perspective this may not be ideal, but you can frame it by telling your users "If you are connected to the internet when you get a high score, your score will be verified and published in the global top list" or something to that effect.  I'm sure you can figure out a way to handle it.

Comment: I almost agree, untrusting scores recorded offline is one of the smart choices. But we can't untrust other game datas such as user's location, item possessions or any flags because game state will be collapsed if we untrust them, and VERIFIED scores can be recorded even the these datas were modified by user.

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to solve 2 problems: 1) users are modifying their game save data (cheating).  2) you want to prevent tampered data from getting published to your server.  To solve #1, you can do things like obfuscating or encrypting the save format as people here have described.  Without knowing more about your specific app its hard to suggest an approach that will do what you need since we don't know what is happening in your app vs on the server.  To solve #2, I think the suggestion above still stands, but again, I don't know the full context of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are some very light, if darn near unbreakable, ciphers for encoding if you want to go that route. I've used in the past a variation of the substitution cipher where I XORed the values with random numbers. These can be darn near unbreakable (esp. if you change it up each time - nothing more frustrating to a hacker than to get differing results each time :)

The smaller the data, the easier it is to back-hack. Nothing is more frustrating than sniffing a network and finding that 10 digits are encoded in a 4096 digit block of random numbers.

Depending on the size of your data, you could encode different parts with different ciphers - it would be lightweight to encode/decode but a pain to hack.

Comment: It seems to be a cost effective solution. But can I use this solution with SQLite databases?

Comment: Yes, but it means storing things as binary data. It's a little more inconvenient, but not a difficult task. One nice aspect about it is that you can make the cipher as easy or as nasty as you want. You can even store the key in SQLite database (just don't call it KEY and make it also hard to figure out exactly WHICH numbers are the key).

Comment: For some code that implements this approach, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10656929/12484

Answer (score -1):

You can save the data in a sub-folder of NSLibraryDirectory instead of NSDocumentsDirectory. Users cannot see or edit the NSLibraryDirectory through iTunes.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there are some tools to mount iPhone as a disk drive, we can modify any data (even in Library directory) on the device by using them :(

Comment: Exactly. I would put my time in light-weight encryption.